# What is the significance of the derivative of a probability density function of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

What is the significance of the derivative of a probability density function of a continuous random variable ?

Comment: In short? None.

Comment: No more significance than derivatives of any other functions.  For example, you might want to use the derivative to find out where the density has a maximum.

Comment: It's the instantaneous rate of change of probability density. </tautology>

Answer (score 4):

It reduces Lebesgue-stielgies integral to the usual Lebesgue integral in computing,which is easier.

Comment: +1 for [spelling Lebesgue correctly](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37990/mathematicians-whose-names-are-commonly-mispronounced), -1 for poor [Stieltjes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration). :)