# Name for derivative of probability density function

Tags: probability

Related: [What is the significance of the derivative of a probability density function of a continuous random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35655/what-is-the-significance-of-the-derivative-of-a-probability-density-function-of)

I am interested to know if there is a name for the derivative of the density function, maybe written by some author in some textbook.

For example, if $P(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function, then the derivative $P'(x)$ has a name (which is the density function).

Is there a good name/interpretation for $P''(x)$, the second derivative of the cumulative distribution function (or first derivative of density function)? Maybe written in some math/statistics textbook by some author?

I am currently doing a coding project, and I want to give it a good name to the first derivative of density function.

```
double probCumulative = 0.95
double probDensity = 0.4
double ....goodname?.... = 0.1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: probDerivative may be good name ?